# Sort a list of objects by object field that is a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a class which has a field that is a numpy array. Instances of this class are in a list. I would like to sort the list by the mentioned arrays. How can I do this?

Simplified:

```
class DataObject:
  def __init__(self, location):
    self.loc = location

do1 = DataObject(array([4.0, 5.0, 6.0]))
do2 = DataObject(array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
do3 = DataObject(array([1.0, 8.0, 9.0]))
dos = [do1, do2, do3]

sorted_dos = awesome_sort(dos)
```

Here I want the order in `sorted_dos` to be do2, do3, do1.

How do I implement `awesome_sort()` elegant and bug-free without changing `DataObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the built-in `sorted` function.  You can pass it a `key` that tells it how to sort the list.

```
sorted(dos, key=lambda x: tuple(x.loc))
```

This will sort ascending based on the first value of the array.  In the event of the first elements being equal, it will then check the second elements.

Comment: Will this sort the arrays as I expect? I did not manage to make a minimal working example with arrays. I tried `a1 = array([1.0, 5.0, 0.0]); a2 = array([1.0, 8.0, 9.0]); a3 = array([1.0, 5.0, 9.0]); a = [a1, a2, a3]; sorted(a)`

Comment: I just made a small fix.  You need to wrap the `tuple` around `x.loc`

Comment: Also, if you want to see the location of your objects you can add `def __repr__(self):    return "<DataObject loc: {}, {}, {}>".format(*self.loc)`

Comment: is that the same as `toString()` in Java/Scala?

Comment: It is similar.  The `__repr__` method determines what is shown when the object is referenced in an output.  There is also a `__str__` method that determines what is displayed when the object is called from`str` or `print`.